# LocalStack and aws-local-cdk - Unable to find integration for path

Tags: aws-cdk, localstack

I'm using LocalStack (running using Docker) and aws-cdk-local for local deployment.

While the deployment process went smooth, When trying to access the API endpoint
'http://localhost:4566/restapis/{rest-id}/{stage-id}/*user_request*/', it returns `{"Type": "User", "message": "Unable to find integration for path /restapis/{rest-id}/{stage-name}/_user_request_/", "__type": "NotFoundException"}`

Did anyone encountered a similar issue?

Any help will be much appreciated.